# Fusion chart automation using protractor automation framework

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, fusioncharts

My current project setup

- Angular js 1.5
- integrated fusion chart https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts
- now am trying protractor framework to automate the application and i could do many things like form validation , input and submit .

Now i have problem with Fusion chart automation , like am not able to validate the data that showing on the graph is correct or not .

i tried below idea but am not able to get reference it giving error fusion chart is not defined .
[outine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpuVt.png)
please comment on the below idea and suggest any other way to automate this or any other new framework .

Answer (score 0):

You can write test cases using FusionCharts life cycle events supported to test but please note chart need to be rendered first on any browser as FusionCharts is a JavaScript charting library that you need to include in your HTML page/application to use or run the charts.

Fusioncharts has its own supported events and methods which you can use like method getCSVData to fetch chart data set in the CSV format which you can later validate if its correct or not as per your requirement.

Refer below doc link for lifecycle Events using AngularJs,
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angularjs/lifecycle-event-using-angularjs

Please refer below doc link for all supported methods with details and samples,
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods

Please refer below doc link for supported events,
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events

Hope this helps.